# I tried uniq function doesn’t work in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, uniq

I have:

- article A with tags: `tags: [chris, mark, scott]`
- article B with tags: `tags: [mark, scott, chris]`

I want to display a list of unique tags for all the articles.

I tried using the `.uniq` function but it doesn’t work.

Here’s the code I have:

```
vars[:tags] = articles.map {|x| x[:tags]}.uniq.join(' ')
```

This results in: `chris, mark, scott mark, scott, chris`

The desired result should be: `chris, mark, scott`

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nested Array after the map. Use [`Array#flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) to reduce its recursion by one level:

```rb
articles.map {|x| x[:tags]}          #=> [["chris", "mark", "scott"], ["mark", "scott", "chris"]]
articles.map {|x| x[:tags]}.flatten  #=> ["chris", "mark", "scott", "mark", "scott", "chris"]
```

So this is what you want:

```rb
vars[:tags] = articles.map {|x| x[:tags]}.flatten.uniq.join(' ')
```

Thanks to [@Stefan](/users/477037/stefan), you can also use [`Enumerable#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) for the same result as `a.map {}.flatten`, which [may even be faster](https://gist.github.com/PragTob/8f037b6cab4bffca411063aced6a7917):

```rb
vars[:tags] = articles.flat_map {|x| x[:tags]}.uniq.join(' ')
```

Comment: or `flat_map` instead of `map`

Comment: @ibug insane! was breaking my brain trying to get it to work! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're joining only uniq tags per article, but if I understand you want to have uniq per article collection so you should do sth like that:

```
vars[:tags] = []
articles.each { |article| vars[:tags] += article[:tags] }
vars[:tags] = vars[:tags].uniq.join(' ')
```

That's base idea to understand what you should achieve: firstly get all tags then get onlu uniq tags. You can write it in many other ways but idea is same.